# Java application to be triggered by key sequence in windows

Tags: java, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

Is it possible to "screen" every key pressed by the user and search for the string that opens the java program? I hope to create a fun application that upon detecting the string "Open sesame" to trigger a window in my program to pop-up. Can this be done with java?

EDIT:
The string that triggers the program is listened for **system-wide**. I'm also wondering wether the use of win-api hooks would be appropriate for this.

Comment: Do you want to capture all the keystrokes within your program?  Or capture all the keystrokes system-wide?

Comment: I would like to listen for the string system-wide and not only in my program.

Answer (score 1):

You can't technically do this in java as java runs in a virtual machine and the actual key buffering occurs at a bios level (filling the keyboard type ahead buffer i mean). You need lower level access than java can provide. There may be work arounds but in general you can't use a language with managed code to do this kind of thing. I have hooked into those api's with C# so maybe that is a possibility with java too but why not just do it in c++/c then.

Comment: My main reason to do this in java is that I'm very comfortable with java and do not know C++/C. Could you elaborate a little bit more on what workarounds exist for this?

Comment: Why not take the plunge out of your comfort zone and learn? Maybe take a look at how [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/) (application launcher, open source) does it.

Comment: see if you can get this project to work with Java, the use an unmanaged dll in in managed (c#) maybe you can figure something out with goole "unmanaged dll java" http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would look into a [Key Listener.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

Comment: Thank you. I've tried to use a Key Listener but they are incapable of listening system-wide.